# Вывод MessangeBox вместо краша программы

Tags: c++, qwidget, messagebox

У меня есть график, который отрисовывается с помощью QCustomplot, и кнопка очистки графика

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clear_clicked()
{
    ui->widget->graph(0)->data()->clear();
    ui->widget->replot();
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку до отрисовки графика происходит краш. Как сделать чтобы выводилось сообщение об ошибке, но программа не крашилась или как исправить эту ошибку?
Компилятор MiniGW

Comment: Вывод message box вместо краша - это ужасная идея. Разумным же решением является вывод в лог (можно просто в стандартный поток ошибок) stacktrace при получении сигнала о segmentation fault (предполагаю что эту ошибку вы и получаете). Это можно сделать, например, с помощью бустовой либы stacktrace - повесить печать на сигнал SEGSEGV

Comment: Спасибо, но я решил убирать кнопку до первой открисовки графика, чтобы краша вообще не происходило

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch А почему плохо показывтаь ошибку в message box-е?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а кто говорил про то, что плохо показывать ошибку в message box? Перечитайте: я писал про краш в результате segmentation fault - это абсолютно другое. Ну а почему: разве это не является очевидным?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Неточно сформулировал, имел в виду ошибку при краше. *"разве это не является очевидным?"* По крайней мере не для меня. :) С одной стороны я видел предупреждения, что в обработчиках сигналов можно выполнять только очень ограниченный набор действий, но с другой стороны последние несколько лет у меня message box в обработчике сегфолта работал нормально.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat то что вы читали - совершенно верно. Ну а что касается того, что у вас "нормально работает", то можно провести аналогию с ездой не пристегнувшись: вы вполне можете игнорировать ПДД, вот только это не отменяет опасность разбиться насмерть. Помимо ограниченности действий есть ещё ОЧЕНЬ большая проблема: код gui априори менее надёжен и подвержен ошибкам, а значит вы можете получить рекурсивный вызов SEGSEGV - а это уже катастрофа. К тому же, помимо технического вопроса, я не вижу пользы от этого: message box предназначен для юзера, а что подобная ошибка может сказать конкретно ему?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Рекурсивый вызов я как-то ловил, да. После этого добавил проверку. А на счет печати в логи - мелкомягкие в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal?view=vs-2019) пишут, что даже `fwrite` вызывать нельзя.